# How to specify what type I need to register to specific type by Autofac

Tags: .net, ioc-container, autofac

I want to specify type of weapon for different warriors

```
public interface IWarrior
{
    string Kill();
}

public interface IWeapon
{
    string KillSound();
}

public class Zombie : IWarrior
{
    private readonly IWeapon _weapon;

    public Zombie(IWeapon weapon)
    {
        _weapon = weapon;
    }

    public string Kill()
    {
        return _weapon.KillSound();
    }
}

public class Soldier : IWarrior
{
    private readonly IWeapon _weapon;

    public Soldier(IWeapon weapon)
    {
        _weapon = weapon;
    }

    public string Kill()
    {
        return _weapon.KillSound();
    }
}

public class Gun : IWeapon
{
    public string KillSound()
    {
        return "Pif-paf";
    }
}

public class Teeth :IWeapon
{
    public string KillSound()
    {
        return "Chew-chew-chew";
    }
}
```

I want to specify something like this:

`builder.RegisterType<Gun>().As<IWeapon>().Where(t => t.Name.Equals("Soldier"));`
`builder.RegisterType<Teeth>().As<IWeapon>().Where(t => t.Name.Equals("Zombie"));`

How I can do this?

Comment: Is what you're trying to do an actual use case? I find these kinds of examples rather problematic, because they not realistic scenarios to use dependency injection in. There are therefore not good examples for explaining DI. Instead try using concepts of the actual application you are trying to build, such as `ILoanCalculator` or `ICustomerRepository`.

Comment: In real world I want to define different DB for different repositories (I use more than one datasources for different datatypes). Like `builder.RegisterType<FirstDbDataContext>().As<IDbDataContext>().Where(t=>t.Name.Contains("someName"));` and `builder.RegisterType<SecondDbDataContext>().As<IDbDataContext>().Where(t=>t.Name.Not.Contains("someName"));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to define different DB for different repositories (I use more
>   than one datasources for different datatypes). Like
>   builder.RegisterType().As().Where(t=>t.Name‌​.Contains("someName"));
>   and
>   builder.RegisterType().As().Where(t=>t.Nam‌​e.Not.Contains("someName"));

It might be better to remove the ambiguity from your design. Your `IDbDataContext` is ambiguous, since `FirstDbDataContext` and `SecondDbDataContext` are not really compatible implementations of the same contract, since they aren't interchangeable; a repository requires a certain database and it will fail when an `IDbDataContext` for the wrong database is passed in.

Try giving each context its own abstraction, such as `IFirstDbDataContext` and `ISecondDbDataContext`. By letting a repository depend explicitly on either of those interfaces it becomes clear to anyone who looks at the constructor what this repository depends on.

But it not only becomes much easier for anyone maintaining the code, it becomes significantly easier to wire everything together using a DI container, simply because you removed the ambiguity.

This is the registration you'll end up with:

```
builder.RegisterType<FirstDbDataContext>().As<IFirstDbDataContext>();
builder.RegisterType<SecondDbDataContext>().As<ISecondDbDataContext>();
```