# Passing contextual data down dependency tree

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject, inversion-of-control

I am using `ninject` to do constructor injection, and my code works something like:

```cs
public class MyRootClass
{
    public MyRootClass(
        [SetContext("catSession")] IRepository<Cat, int> catRep,
        [SetContext("dogSession")] IRepository<Dog, int> dogRep))
    {
        //set some stuff here
    }                 
}

public class GenericRepository<TEntity, TID> : IRepository<TEntity, TID>
{
    public GenericRepository(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        //set some stuff here
    }
}

public class MyUnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    //sessionFactory should be bound to the either a cat session, or dog
    //session depending on what the caller (MyRootClass) has currently
    //set in the context
    public MyUnitOfWork([ReadContext] ISessionFactory sessionFactory)
    {
        //set some stuff here
    }
}
```

The `ISessionFactory` will have a binding for each session (cat and dog) bound in a `NinjectModule`. They are Named bindings. I essentially want to be able to ask for an `IRepository<TEntity, TID>` to be injected into a calling class, and have the calling class specify what session the repository should be using behind the scenes.

How can I go about setting up some contextual variable in `MyRootClass` that can be used to determine which session `Ninject` should inject somewhere down the dependency tree?

Comment: You might want to reconsider your design. Your design adds a lot of complexity, makes your DI configuration brittle and pollutes your application code with DI specific information (the attributes).

Comment: I agree, I would like to get away from the attributes, but I am not sure exactly how to go about this using ninject. Do you have any suggestions on where to start?

Comment: Can you explain a 'session' is in your case and why you need to have two different sessions at the same time?

Comment: It is an NHibernate `ISessionFactory`. We set up a `SessionFactory` for each database that we need to be able to communicate with. I believe my wording was misleading in the original post, there will be a cat SessionFactory and a Dog SessionFactory, not a cat and dog Session. Our application might need two different `SessionFactory` objects because we need to be able to communicate to different types of DBs. @Steven

Comment: So, your CatRepository will always need a CatSessionFactory, or might do you need to be able to let the CatRepository use the DogSessionFactory?

Comment: CatRepository will always use the CatSessionFactory and dog with dog one in this example. The idea of the `[SetContext("catSession")]` is to allow the `MyRootClass`to set a variable that can be read off in `MyUnitOfWork` indicating which `SessionFactory` ninject should use.   @Steven

Comment: There's some ambiguity in your design. Take a look at this related advice: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20160033/how-to-specify-what-type-i-need-to-register-to-specific-type-by-autofac/20164419#20164419

Comment: @Steven: While your suggestion often make sense, in other times it can lead to a case of severe code duplicitis.
How about using different ninject kernels instead? The CAT kernel only knows about CAT stuff, the DOG kernel only knows about dog stuff. Configure the ISessionFactory in both kernels accordingly. Of course this requires a way for the "rest" of the application to access the CAT and DOG stuff, so i suggest to basically build a subsystem for each with a nice interface.

Comment: How many different data models is your application connecting to? Usually just a few. Since each database has a total different interface (you can't request a cat from the DogDatabase) you should act as such. Creating multiple kernels is almost always not a good solution.